# How to hide extra top and bottom of an image inside its container?

Tags: html, css

What I mean is that there's an image with dimensions **W**: 200px, **H**: 300px. It is inside an **inline-block** element **div**. The height and width of div are 200px, 200px. So there's 100px of extra part of the image, which is flowing out of the div, in vertical direction. I don't want to change the dimensions of the image. I just want to **vertically** align that image in the **middle** of div, that means equal portions of image from top and bottom would be out of the div. And later I want to **hide** those extra parts.
Example:

```
<div id="body">
 <div id="container">
  <img src=""/>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any solution? Using CSS?

Comment: Make the image the background to the div and set `background-position: center; `?

Comment: Nope. I don't want that. It's an image gallery. There are many similar images with similar containers.

Comment: If the difference is the same for each image, you can set a negative top margin equal to half the difference, and set `overflow:hidden` on the container

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `transform: translateY();` and `overflow: hidden`.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
This <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/animals/5"/> become this
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/animals/5"/>
</div>
```

---

As you use fixed width/height on your div's, here is a great tips using the background property and still set the image source in the markup, as done with images.

A solution like this will center and crop any sized image.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: center center / cover;
}
```

```html
These becoms like this<br>
<div class="container" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/300/animals/5)">
</div>
<div class="container" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/7)">
</div>
<div class="container" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/600/animals/3)">
</div>

<br>which originally looks like this<br>

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/animals/5">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/7">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/600/animals/3">
```

Comment: There are many more images. So it would affect them too! I would keep adding/removing images. So I can't assign them IDs either.

Comment: @VikasKumar Did my update help you, and if no, what else can I do to make it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Add an `overflow:hidden` to the `.container` which wraps the `<img>` and give the `.container` a `position:relative`.
Then give the Image a `position:absoulte` relative to the `.container`.

After this move the Image **50px** to the top, relative to the `.container` to vertically center the `<img>`.

Here is a working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/87gjtje6/3/

```css
.container {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:solid 5px red;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.container img {
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    top:-50px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x300/000/fff">
</div>
```

Comment: No. If you see the first scenario, the 200x300 doesn't lie in the vertical middle of the red square!

Comment: It works! `position:relative` to container is the must!
Could you kindly explain why `position:relative` is the must?

Is it because the img is set to `position:absoulte`?

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox would be the most up to date method

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="">
</div>

<h3> Original Image </h3>

<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a not so simple solution,but it can be applied to any element to place it at the centre

```
img{
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top:-100px;/*half of the height*/
  margin-left:-150px;/*half of the width*/
}
```

Now for the parent div its quite easy you can just give 'overflow:hidden' property.  i.e

```
.container{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to this would be to set the image as a background for the "container" div:

```
div#container{
    background: #ebebeb url("...image-url...") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This will show only the part of the image, that is inside the div, and the rest will be hidden. Look for more info on how to do it at CSS-tricks.

If you just want to hide a part of the image just use

```
 #container{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

If you want to place the image at the center of the div there is another way as well, but it is a bit complex and you need to use jQuery. The way it works is by using the `overflow: hidden` property for the "container" div.

```
var height = ... //div height
var width = ... //div width
var croppedimg = document.getElementsByClassName("cropped-image")[0];
var imgwidth = parseInt(croppedimg.offsetWidth);
var imgheight = parseInt(croppedimg.offsetHeight);
if (imgwidth > imgheight) {
    croppedimg.style.height = height;
    croppedimg.style.width = "auto";
    croppedimg.style.marginLeft = "-" + (($(croppedimg).width() - width) / 2) + "px";
 } else {
    croppedimg.style.width = height;
    croppedimg.style.height = "auto";
    croppedimg.style.marginTop = "-" + (($(croppedimg).height() - width) / 2) + "px";
 }
```

The way this works is this:
We place the image inside the "container" div and give it `className = "cropped-image"`. Then we use some javascript code to resize the img inside the div. After that we use `margin-left` and `margin-top`, to place the image at the center of the div. Because of the property `overflow: hidden` in the "container" div we won't see the part of the image that is outside the div.